# Approximate an Integration by a linear formula

Tags: calculus, integration, approximation

I just wonder are there any methods to approximate the following integration by a linear formula ?
$$
\int_{x_1}^{x_2} \int_{y_1}^{y_2} f( x,y,w_1,\dots,w_n ) \, dx \, dy  \approx \sum\limits_{i = 1}^n a_i w_i + b,
$$
where $a_i$ and $b$ are constants.
For example $f( x,y,w_1,\dots,w_n ) $ $= e^{ - \frac{x^2 + y^2}{2}} \ln \left( \sum\limits_{i = 1}^n w_i e^{-\frac{(x-i)^2+(y-i)^2}{2} } \right)$.

Comment: The TeX code in your question was abominable.  Things like {{ \left( {x}^{2} \right) }} where (x^2) would suffice.  Putting curly braces around long expressions where they serve no purpose.  Lots of stuff like that.  I've cleaned it up.

Comment: Thanks! I used MathType because I'm not good at Latex.

Answer (score 2):

Let 
$$
g(w) = \iint f( x,y,{w_1},...,{w_n}) 
$$
then
$$
g_{w_i}(\bar w) = \int\int f_{w_i} (x,y,\bar w) dx\,dy
$$
and for $w\to \bar w$
$$
g(w) \approx g(\bar w) + \sum_i g_{w_i}(\bar w) (w-\bar w)_i
$$

Comment: What is $f_{w_i} (x,y,\bar w)$ ?

Comment: the partial derivative of $f$ with respect to $w_i$